# How to speed up SVG morphing

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-animate

I am building a filtering menu for a shop, and I am using svg morphing to animate some svg's, it works well when an svg is accessed by `getElementById`, but everything gets performance hits when in a loop.
This is my js:

```
var iconNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".button-filter");
    

iconNodes.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (item.classList.contains("open")) {
      item.classList.remove("open");
      item.getElementsByClassName('anim-up')[0].beginElement();
      item.getElementsByClassName("button-text")[0].innerHTML = "Open";
    } else {
      item.classList.add("open");
      item.getElementsByClassName('anim-down')[0].beginElement();
      item.getElementsByClassName("button-text")[0].innerHTML = "Close";
    }
  })
});
```

And html:

```
<button type="button" class="button-filter">
    <div class=""><span class="button-text">Discount</span>
        <svg id="dropdown" viewBox="0 0 194.6 185.1" class="inline-block w-10 h-10">
            <polygon fill="#A2A7AA" points="53.4,65.1 96.6,65.1 75,90.1 75,90.1">
                <animate class="anim-up" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="75,65.1 75,65.1 96.6,90.1 53.4,90.1"/>
                <animate class="anim-down" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="53.4,65.1 96.6,65.1 75,90.1 75,90.1"/>
            </polygon>
        </svg>
    </div>
</button>
```

How could I change my approach?

Comment: Please describe exactly what happens. What loop are you referrencing to? And where does porformance hits occur? Is the loop adding the event listeners slow, or is the animation choppy? Is executing multiple animations at once the problem?

Comment: Often svg animation doesn't play smoothly, stutters of jumps from the beginning straight to the end.

Comment: Using `<animate>` means you leave all prioritizing and execution speed to the browser, with no further influence from your side. Note that glitches you see on your browser might or might not be experienced on other browsers, or other hardware/OS/driver/software setups. All you can influence is how many animations are executed in parallel, or moving other time-consuming operations (DOM tree traversing could be among them, but that is subject to testing) to times when there is no animation.